# laravel4-send more than one array from controller to view

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have created a small applications and I am creating an edit form. I have 2 tables one "cars" and the other named "classes". Table clrs has a field named class which has all id of table classes. I have join query which gets data from 2 tables and displays at the form. The problem is that I want to create a dropdown list at field "class" which gets all classes from table classes and displays with a dropdown, but also I want to set the default value the class which is the id in table "cars".

```
 public function edit($id) {
        $values = DB::table('cars')
                ->join('classes', 'cars.class', '=', 'classes.id')
                ->select('cars.*', 'classes.class')
                ->where ('cars.id','=',$id)
                ->get();
        return View::make('pages.edit')->with('values', $values);
    }
```

edit.blade.php

```
<div class="form-group">
                {{ Form::label('class', 'Class', array('class'=>'control-label col-lg-4')) }}
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    {{ Form::text('class', $v->class, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
                </div>
            </div>
```

I want to create an other query at controller that gets all classes existing in table classes and to put them at the form as a dropdown list. I don't know how to pass 2 arrays at view. I really need some help

Comment: Do you mean `View::make(...)->with('values1',$values1)->with('values2',$values2)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just [pass an array](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#views), it's way easier:

```
    public function edit($id) {
      $data['values'] = DB::table('cars')
                      ->join('classes', 'cars.class', '=', 'classes.id')
                      ->select('cars.*', 'classes.class')
                      ->where ('cars.id','=',$id)
                     ->get();
      $data['otherArray'] = ['other', 'elements'];
      $data['anotherVar'] = 'This is just a string';

      return View::make('pages.edit', $data);
   }
```

In your view you'll have `$values`, `$otherArray`, `$anotherVar` and so on.

Comment: @foreach ($values as $v) shows me the error: undefined variable values

Comment: It works now. The problem is with foreach now. Because at dropdown I want to show as default value the value of class that I get from $values and as dropdown options all the values from second array

Comment: Form::select('class', $second_array, $values->id); The second parameter is your list of options, the third one, your default value.

Comment: {{ Form::select('class', $class , $v->class) }} and it doesn't appear. the default value is blank

Comment: the same problem as http://laravel.io/forum/02-12-2014-formselect-default-value-lv-41